# PdfBox - PDColorSpaceFactory.createColorSpace(document, iccColorSpace) throws nullpointerexception

Tags: java, pdfbox

I'm trying to create a PDF which has a single image on a single page. The tricky part is to use a custom (defined in a separate file) CMYK color space.

I've tried to call

> PDColorSpaceFactory.createColorSpace(document, iccColorSpace)

but keep getting nullpointerexception. I've managed to track the issue up to the constructor:

```
public PDICCBased( PDDocument doc )
{
    array = new COSArray();
    array.add( COSName.ICCBASED );
    array.add( new PDStream( doc ) );
}
```

The **PDICCBased** object has **stream** field and it's obviously not set. Thus when it's called at:

```
public static PDColorSpace createColorSpace( PDDocument doc, ColorSpace cs ) throws IOException
{
    PDColorSpace retval = null;
    if( cs.isCS_sRGB() )
    {
        retval = PDDeviceRGB.INSTANCE;
    }
    else if( cs instanceof ICC_ColorSpace )
    {
        ICC_ColorSpace ics = (ICC_ColorSpace)cs;
        PDICCBased pdCS = new PDICCBased( doc );
        retval = pdCS;
        COSArray ranges = new COSArray();
        for( int i=0; i<cs.getNumComponents(); i++ )
        {
            ranges.add( new COSFloat( ics.getMinValue( i ) ) );
            ranges.add( new COSFloat( ics.getMaxValue( i ) ) );
        }
        PDStream iccData = pdCS.getPDStream();
        OutputStream output = null;
        try
        {
            output = iccData.createOutputStream(); <<<<<<<<<-------------
            output.write( ics.getProfile().getData() );
        }
        finally
        {
            if( output != null )
            {
                output.close();
            }
        }
        pdCS.setNumberOfComponents( cs.getNumComponents() );
    }
    else
    {
        throw new IOException( "Not yet implemented:" + cs );
    }
    return retval;
}
```

A NullPointerException is thrown.

Am I missing something? Is there another\ better way to create PDF usinf CMYK color space?

Updated **createColorSpace**:

```
    public static PDColorSpace createColorSpace( PDDocument doc, ColorSpace cs ) throws IOException
{
    PDColorSpace retval = null;
    if( cs.isCS_sRGB() )
    {
        retval = PDDeviceRGB.INSTANCE;
    }
    else if( cs instanceof ICC_ColorSpace )
    {
        ICC_ColorSpace ics = (ICC_ColorSpace)cs;

        // CREATING MANUALLY THE COS ARR  ****************************
        COSArray cosArray = new COSArray();  
        cosArray.add(COSName.ICCBASED);
        PDStream pdStream = new PDStream(doc);
        cosArray.add(pdStream.getStream());

        // USING DIFFERENT CONSTRUTOR  *******************************
        PDICCBased pdCS = new PDICCBased( cosArray );
        retval = pdCS;
        COSArray ranges = new COSArray();
        for( int i=0; i<cs.getNumComponents(); i++ )
        {
            ranges.add( new COSFloat( ics.getMinValue( i ) ) );
            ranges.add( new COSFloat( ics.getMaxValue( i ) ) );
        }
        PDStream iccData = pdCS.getPDStream();
        OutputStream output = null;
        try
        {
            output = ((COSStream)iccData.getCOSObject()).createFilteredStream();
            output.write( ics.getProfile().getData() );
        }
        finally
        {
            if( output != null )
            {
                output.close();
            }
        }
        pdCS.setNumberOfComponents( cs.getNumComponents() );
    }
    else
    {
        throw new IOException( "Not yet implemented:" + cs );
    }
    return retval;
}
```

That did the trick from creating the colorSpace.

The creation of ColorSpace from a custom icc and applying it to a given image:

```
ICC_ColorSpace iccColorSpace = new ICC_ColorSpace(ICC_Profile.getInstance("C:\\...\\USWebCoatedSWOP.icc")); 
ColorConvertOp op = new ColorConvertOp(image.getColorModel().getColorSpace(), iccColorSpace, null);
image = op.filter(image, null);
```

The creation of the PDF:

```
PDDocument document = new PDDocument();

PDColorSpace colorSpace = createColorSpace(document, iccColorSpace);

PDPage blankPage = new PDPage(new PDRectangle(100, 100));
document.addPage(blankPage);

PDPageContentStream pdPageContentStream = new PDPageContentStream(document, blankPage);

PDXObjectImage pdxObjectImage = new PDPixelMap(document, image);
pdxObjectImage.setColorSpace(colorSpace);
pdPageContentStream.drawXObject(pdxObjectImage, 0, 0, imagePostScriptWidth, imagePostScriptHeight);
pdPageContentStream.close();

document.save(byteArrayOutputStream);
document.close();
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Can you include the stack trace of the error?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, this seems to be a bug with the first constructor. You could use the second constructor, which uses a COSArray:

The PDF spec explains what to do:

"An ICCBased colour space shall be an array: [/ICCBased stream]"

So you need to create a COSArray, with COSName.ICCBASED as first element, and a COSStream with your ICC data in the second. Create a COSStream and write to it with createFilteredStream(). That COSArray you can use for the second constructor.

Alternatively, just use PDDeviceCMYK.INSTANCE as the colorspace :-)

Update:
I have opened issue [PDFBOX-2812](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PDFBOX-2812) and it has been fixed. You can get a snapshot in a few hours [here](https://repository.apache.org/content/groups/snapshots/org/apache/pdfbox/pdfbox-app/1.8.10-SNAPSHOT/).

Comment: thanks @Tilman, got it out. However I still can't get the desired result: I manage to generate a PDColorSpace from a custom icc file. I use pdxObjectImage.setColorSpace(colorSpace) to set the image colorSpace and pdPageContentStream.drawXObject to write it but the result is a mass. Any thoughts?

Comment: @Eddie-Sh can't help without getting more code and the PDF (upload it somewhere). Btw for images, use drawImage. "but the result is a mass" is not really a good error description.

Comment: Updated the question with the complete code. Thanks.

Comment: @Eddie-Sh but it is still unclear what the question is now. Is there still an NPE? Or has the image the wrong colors? Is it at the wrong position?

Comment: the NPE is resolved. Please review a screen shot of the PDF: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7YmdQBTCKHXRTNzSG5hZGRsU3M/view?usp=sharing   note that when opening the PDF in adobe and scrolling down I get the following:     https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7YmdQBTCKHXY1dESGVDODJWWjQ/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Sadly, I think the problem is that your colorspace has 4 components, but your image has 3. (You said it is CMYK). Sorry I didn't realize it earlier, but I doubt that it can be done with PDFBox at all. (We do support rendering CMYK images, but that isn't what your question is about, you want to create a PDF)