# How do you extract color profiles from a PDF file using pdfbox (or other open source Java lib)

Tags: java, pdf, pdfbox

Once you've loaded a document:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    PDDocument doc = PDDocument.load(new File("blah.pdf"));
```

How do you get the page by page printing color intent from the PDDocument? I read the docs, didn't see coverage.

Comment: 1) can you share the PDF? 2) are you aware that not all PDF have icc color profiles? 3) Do you need this for many files or just for one? 4) please try PDFDebugger with your file.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.

1) Any PDF
2) No, wasn't still trying to groc color profiles. The question is more general now
3) Any file, I'm trying to pull per-page or whole doc (depending on what's possible) color profiles
4) Trying to do this programmatically. I'd just use a UI tool if this was a single file solve.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This gets the output intents (you'll get these with high quality PDF files) and also the icc profiles for colorspaces and images:

```
    PDDocument doc = PDDocument.load(new File("XXXXX.pdf"));
    for (PDOutputIntent oi : doc.getDocumentCatalog().getOutputIntents())
    {
        COSStream destOutputIntent = oi.getDestOutputIntent();
        String info = oi.getOutputCondition();
        if (info == null || info.isEmpty())
        {
            info = oi.getInfo();
        }
        InputStream is = destOutputIntent.createInputStream();
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(info + ".icc");
        IOUtils.copy(is, fos);
        fos.close();
        is.close();
    }
    for (int p = 0; p < doc.getNumberOfPages(); ++p)
    {
        PDPage page = doc.getPage(p);
        for (COSName name : page.getResources().getColorSpaceNames())
        {
            PDColorSpace cs = page.getResources().getColorSpace(name);
            if (cs instanceof PDICCBased)
            {
                PDICCBased iccCS = (PDICCBased) cs;
                InputStream is = iccCS.getPDStream().createInputStream();
                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(System.currentTimeMillis() + ".icc");
                IOUtils.copy(is, fos);
                fos.close();
                is.close();
            }
        }
        for (COSName name : page.getResources().getXObjectNames())
        {
            PDXObject x = page.getResources().getXObject(name);
            if (x instanceof PDImageXObject)
            {
                PDImageXObject img = (PDImageXObject) x;
                if (img.getColorSpace() instanceof PDICCBased)
                {
                    InputStream is = ((PDICCBased) img.getColorSpace()).getPDStream().createInputStream();
                    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(System.currentTimeMillis() + ".icc");
                    IOUtils.copy(is, fos);
                    fos.close();
                    is.close();
                }
            }
        }
    }
    doc.close();
```

What this doesn't do (but I could add some of it if needed):

- colorspaces of shadings, patterns, xobject forms, appearance stream resources
- recursion in colorspaces like DeviceN and Separation
- recursion in patterns, xobject forms, soft masks

Comment: Do you happen to know if there's any way to detect Pantone match?

Comment: @stevedbrown Don't know about these. I can only tell you where there are icc profiles, not their quality.

Answer (score 2):

I read the examples on "How to create/add Intents to a PDF file". I couldn't get an example on "How to get intents". Using the API/examples, I wrote the following (untested code) to get the [COSStream](https://pdfbox.apache.org/docs/2.0.3/javadocs/) object for each of the Intents. See if this is useful for you.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
  PDDocument doc = PDDocument.load(new File("blah.pdf"));

  PDDocumentCatalog cat = doc.getDocumentCatalog();
  List<PDOutputIntent> list = cat.getOutputIntents();

  for (PDOutputIntent e : list) {
    p("PDOutputIntent Found:");
    p("Info="+e.getInfo());
    p("OutputCondition="+e.getOutputCondition());
    p("OutputConditionIdentifier="+e.getOutputConditionIdentifier());
    p("RegistryName="+e.getRegistryName());
    COSStream cstr = e.getDestOutputIntent();
  }

  static void p(String s) {
    System.out.println(s);
  }
}
```

Comment: I beleive the difference is in versions  [2.0.2](https://pdfbox.apache.org/docs/2.0.2/javadocs/org/apache/pdfbox/pdmodel/PDDocumentCatalog.html) versus [1.8.11](http://pdfbox.apache.org/docs/1.8.11/javadocs/org/apache/pdfbox/pdmodel/PDDocumentCatalog.html)

Comment: @stevedbrown, I got handle on the stream but ran out of time while trying to interpret the contents of the stream as "ICC Profile". Did you get what you wanted? If your issue is not resolved, let us know your questions. We will try our best here (individually or together) to get a complete picture.

Answer (score 2):

Using `itext pdf` library (fork of an older version 4.2.1) you could do smth. like:

```
PdfReader reader = new com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfReader(Path pathToPdf);
PRStream stream = (PRStream) reader.getCatalog().getAsDict(PdfName.DESTOUTPUTPROFILE);
if (stream != null)
 {
  byte[] destProfile = PdfReader.getStreamBytes(stream);
 }
```

For extracting the profile from each page you could iterate over each page like

```
for(int i = 1; i <= pdfReader.getNumberOfPages(); i++)
 {
  PRStream prStream = (PRStream) pdfReader.getPageN(i).getDirectObject(PdfName.DESTOUTPUTPROFILE);
 if (stream != null)
  {
   byte[] destProfile = PdfReader.getStreamBytes(stream);
  }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know whether this code help or not, after searching below links,

> [How do I add an ICC to an existing PDF document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34138201/how-do-i-add-an-icc-to-an-existing-pdf-document)
>
> [PdfBox - PDColorSpaceFactory.createColorSpace(document, iccColorSpace) throws nullpointerexception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30443174/pdfbox-pdcolorspacefactory-createcolorspacedocument-icccolorspace-throws-nu)
>
> https://pdfbox.apache.org/docs/1.8.11/javadocs/org/apache/pdfbox/pdmodel/graphics/color/PDICCBased.html

I found some code, check whether it help or not,

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
  PDDocument doc = PDDocument.load(new File("blah.pdf"));

  PDDocumentCatalog cat = doc.getDocumentCatalog();
  List<PDOutputIntent> list = cat.getOutputIntents();

  PDDocumentCatalog cat = doc.getDocumentCatalog();
  COSArray cosArray = doc.getCOSObject();
  PDICCBased pdCS = new PDICCBased( cosArray );

  pdCS.getNumberOfComponents()

  static void p(String s) {
    System.out.println(s);
  }
}
```

Comment: Leaving the unused static void p in this code makes this feel a lot like blackpen's answer.

Comment: `PDDocumentCatalog cat = doc.getDocumentCatalog();
  COSArray cosArray = doc.getCOSObject();
  PDICCBased pdCS = new PDICCBased( cosArray );` copied his code and added these 3 lines ;)

Comment: @Hemakumar _"copied his code and added these 3 lines ;)"_ I'd call this plagiarism, and you shouldn't copy and paste code from other answers. Shame on you.

Comment: @Marcs how will you fix bug in someone else's code.... without using their code...? I don't copied and pasted the same answer... I modified the code, where I felt like some modifications needed. Question needs the correct Solution, I tried give my views that's it. Thanks for feeling shame on me. I have no worries with that. :)

Comment: @Hemakumar _how will you fix bug in someone else's code..._ You post a comment to the answer and address the bug, what you've done is just plain stealing.