# Detect if a PDF is black and white or not in Java

Tags: java, pdf, colors

I have to print hundreds of single page PDF files and I wonder if I can detect if a PDF is black and white or color, I want to send black and white pdfs to a print queue and color ones to another.

I'm processing these pdfs in Java, can someone suggest me some technique?

Comment: What if there are RGB images but they are just grey?

Comment: It might be worth a try to use PDFBox to render into an image at a low resolution, then check the image whether all colors are grey (i.e. r=g=b). (I do expect grey and not just black and white, due to interpolation). However this will not be very fast and will use lots of energy.

Comment: Thanks @Tilman but it takes too much time to process pdfs.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could give a try to PDFBox

In this example they extract an .icc (color profile) so may be what you are looking for.

[How do you extract color profiles from a PDF file using pdfbox (or other open source Java lib)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40521914/how-do-you-extract-color-profiles-from-a-pdf-file-using-pdfbox-or-other-open-so)